# Angular 1.2 apply animation based on class

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I made an HTML layout that works as a filter and my HTML looks something like this:

```
<div class="filter">
    <small>User</small>
    <em ng-bind="filter.name">All Users</em>
    <nav>
        <a class="selected" ng-click="filter={name: 'All Users', filter: ''}">All Users</a>
        <hr>
        <a ng-click="filter={name: 'Person1', filter: 'Person1'}">Person1</a>
        <a ng-click="filter={name: 'Person2', filter: 'Person2'}">Person2</a>
        <a ng-click="filter={name: 'Person3', filter: 'Person3'}">Person3</a>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Now my approach is I created a directive and when I press on the filter, it adds an active class near the filter class, and with CSS when the active class is applied, I show the

```
.filter nav {
    display: none;
}
.filter.active nav {
    display: block;
}
```

My question is: is there any way can I do the show / hide of the nav div animated using the Angular 1.2 animation library?

Thank you in advance, Daniel.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to review [ngAnimate](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate) documentation hide/show animation comes (along with others) comes for almost free. You just need to reference ngAnimate, inject $animate and add the enter/leave css styles.